# Facing Problem with Xpath if then else concept

Tags: .net, xml, xpath-2.0

XML:

```
<additionalFields>
    <field name="dataKey">3868</field>
    <field name="distribution">140</field>
</additionalFields>
```

I would like to execute following If else Xpath statement.

```
String text = nav.Evaluate("if(/additionalFields/field[@name='distribution']/text() = '140') then 'C' else ' ' ").ToString();
```

However I am getting following error message:

> 'if(/additionalFields/field[@name='distribution']/text() = '140') then 'C' else ' ' ' has an invalid token.

Is there any other way to achieve the result? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the .NET Framework. It does **not implement all XPath 2.0 features** yet.
In your specific example there is not problem since you can do the logic in your code.

If this won't fit your need, you can use either **XSLT** for that (although it is much too complex for simpler needs).

Another way would be to use third party libraries which support **XPath 2.0** or **XQuery**, for example **SAXON** or **XQSharp**.

Comment: Yes the above is in .Net framework only. Here the logic within code will force the logic to be hardcoded. We need it to driven by customer will. A simple if else is required but if & else conditional values needs to be customer driven